# How to Split the String by symbol name and Date in this case

Tags: java

I have got a String in this format

**FUTSTKACC28-APR-2016**

ACC is a symbol and 28-APR-2016 is a expiry date
FUTSTK is predefined word

How to retrieve values symbol and Date in this case

For example how to get 
ACC

and

28-APR-2016

some sample data

```
FUTSTKACC26-MAY-2016
FUTSTKACC28-APR-2016
FUTSTKACC30-JUN-2016
FUTSTKADANIENT26-MAY-2016
FUTSTKADANIENT28-APR-2016
FUTSTKADANIENT30-JUN-2016
```

Comment: Do they have a fixed length?

Comment: Date is of fixed length .

Comment: And The other two?

Comment: Symbol name is not fixed

Comment: Then how do you know that "ACC is a symbol, and FUTSTK is predefined word", and not "TKACC is a symbol, and FUTS is predefined word"

Comment: What have you attempted? And where did you encounter a problem?

Comment: I have attached some sample data for reference

Comment: How can one decide which is a symbol from the above String? @PreethiJain

Comment: Is the date always at the end of the line?

Comment: So, basically, each line is `FUTSTK`, then a series of uppercase letters which is a symbol and the rest is the date? You first have to formalise your data if you want to go any further; only then will you be able to start implementing a solution. "Show me your data, I'll show you the code" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a fixed length prefix word and a fixed length date. You can remove the prefix, and then take the substrings from the right by the 11 characters in your dates. Something like,

```
String[] sample = { "FUTSTKACC26-MAY-2016", "FUTSTKACC28-APR-2016", 
        "FUTSTKACC30-JUN-2016", "FUTSTKADANIENT26-MAY-2016", 
        "FUTSTKADANIENT28-APR-2016", "FUTSTKADANIENT30-JUN-2016" };
String predefWord = "FUTSTK";
for (String input : sample) {
    if (input.startsWith(predefWord)) {
        input = input.substring(predefWord.length());
        // There are 11 characters in the date format
        String symbol = input.substring(0, input.length() - 11);
        String dateStr = input.substring(input.length() - 11);
        System.out.printf("symbol=%s, date=%s%n", symbol, dateStr);
    }
}
```

Output is

```
symbol=ACC, date=26-MAY-2016
symbol=ACC, date=28-APR-2016
symbol=ACC, date=30-JUN-2016
symbol=ADANIENT, date=26-MAY-2016
symbol=ADANIENT, date=28-APR-2016
symbol=ADANIENT, date=30-JUN-2016
```

Comment: nice solution i was using lot of replaceAll functions , thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
final String PATTERN = "(FUTSTK)(.+)(\d\d-\w\w\w-\d\d\d\d)"

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
Matcher m = p.matcher("FUTSTKACC28-APR-2016");

String symbol = m.group(1);

DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex approach (bits stolen from @ElliottFrisch) assuming you know the predefined word:

```
String[] sample = { "FUTSTKACC26-MAY-2016", "FUTSTKACC28-APR-2016",
        "FUTSTKACC30-JUN-2016", "FUTSTKADANIENT26-MAY-2016",
        "FUTSTKADANIENT28-APR-2016", "FUTSTKADANIENT30-JUN-2016" };
String predefined = "FUTSTK";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(predefined) + "(\\w+)(\\d\\d-\\w\\w\\w-\\d\\d\\d\\d)");
for (String s: sample) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2));
    }
}
```

output:

```
ACC 26-MAY-2016
ACC 28-APR-2016
ACC 30-JUN-2016
ADANIENT 26-MAY-2016
ADANIENT 28-APR-2016
ADANIENT 30-JUN-2016
```

Comment: OK, while this is not a given, maybe the `predefined` here contains regex metacharacters as well; for "added security" (meh), you could use `Pattern.quote(predefined)` in your `Pattern` definition

Answer (score 0):

```
    final String str = "FUTSTKACCCCCCC28-APR-2016";
    final String[] strArr = str.split("-");
    final String month = strArr[0].substring(strArr[0].length() - 2);
    final String word = strArr[0].substring(0, strArr[0].length() - 2);

    System.out.println("word: " + word);
    System.out.println("date: " + month + "-" + strArr[1] + "-" + strArr[2]);
```